# Solr Config change not being picked up

Tags: solr

I'm trying to remove an unneeded ScriptUpdateProcessor that sits in Solr-home/configsets/myConfig/conf. I have removed the offending lines in processAdd and saved it. I then restarted my docker container where Solr lives.

The problem is it seems to still have a reference to this file and fails to add my document because it falls over due to missing date that the ScriptUpdateProcess needs. How can I force a refresh of this I assumed a restart would be enough! I've done a find across the entire server for a file of this name and can only find the one so I don't think that I have edited the wrong file or anything like that!

I have in addition to a server restart reloaded each core. Still no joy.

NB We are using Solr 5 in Cloud mode

Answer (score 0):

After much wasted time.. I hadn't considered the fact it was running with Apache Zookeeper. Hence the config was loaded into zookeeper and I needed to make the changes there and then reload each core.